# How to access global variable declared in xaml from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources

I want to access an object from different navigation pages in wpf. For that, i created a class and declared in app.xaml. i can access the class from multiple navigation pages in xaml, but when i want to  create button click event in code behind, i cant access the class.

Heres what i did.

The class(SerialComm.cs).

```
class SerialComm : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private SerialPort _serialPortComm;

    public SerialComm()
    {
        _serialPortComm = new SerialPort();
    }

    public SerialPort SerialPortComm
    {
        get { return _serialPortComm; }
        set
        {
            _serialPortComm = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SerialPortComm");
        }
    }

    #region NotifyPropertyChange handler
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion

}
```

resource dictionary (/Resources/DataSourceResources.xaml)

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RemoteConfigurator"
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                mc:Ignorable="d" 
                >
<local:SerialComm x:Key="SerialCommDataSource" d:IsDataSource="True" />
```

Declaration in app.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="RemoteConfigurator.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RemoteConfigurator"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/DataSourceResources.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

navigation page where i can access the object.

```
<UserControl x:Class="RemoteConfigurator.Content.SerialSettings"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:ports="clr-namespace:System.IO.Ports;assembly=System"
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RemoteConfigurator"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="600" Loaded="SerialSettings_Loaded">

<Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SerialCommDataSource}}" >
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="4">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Baud Rate (bps)" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="150"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="tbbaudRate" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" MinWidth="200" Text="{Binding SerialPortComm.BaudRate}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
    **<Button Content="Connect" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="Button_Connect"/>**
</Grid>
```

The problem for me is how do i access the SerialPort from code behind? where do the class actually declared. iirc, i never call any serial port constructor.

here are the code behind.

```
        private void Button_Connect(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        **//SerialPortComm - doesnt work**
        **//SerialCommDataSource - doest work**
    }
```

How can i access the serial port object from code behind?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
App.Current.Resources["SerialCommDataSource"] as SerialCom;
```

Basically as you have added a global resource with key `SerialCommDataSource` you can get it like above

Comment: That works. Thanks. Seems like im wasting my time writing long questions.:)

Comment: @publicENEMY Never, It is always good to have a nice small complete code sample to illustrate your problem. If your problem wasn't this simple it would have definitely helped